# jQuery Modal Popup - Input Type set to null after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a javascript function that gets a modal to displays after postback.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    //$('#EmailMarketingModal').parent().appendTo($("form:first"))
    if ($('[id$=hdf_ShowModal]').val() == "true") {
        $('#EmailMarketingModal').modal({ show: true });
    }
}
```

This is set in my code-behind file.  This all works fine. However, I've noticed that the modal is always being created outside the form tag which means when I try to resubmit data on my form, the input type values are set to null.  Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance. 
Rob

Comment: Can you post the html with the form please. You have to ensure the modal html is inside the form

Comment: For [jQuery dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo); And also for bootstrap modals [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28386761/3591300) might help you more.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ui, from 1.10, has a property 'appendTo'.
Please, check [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo)