# append bootstrap calendar on div not on body

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to open a bootstrap calendar in a modal(popup) window. by default it append on body. is there is any way to append that calendar on a div.

Actually when scroll the page the calendar goes out away through to the popup window.    [image]

Comment: any code? error? screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal window inside another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555585/bootstrap-modal-window-inside-another-div)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. Add content in modal-body.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createapp">
ABC</a>

            <div class="modal fade" id="createapp" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I want to target bootstrap calendar  on a div. currently default it append to body.