# How to append a React modal to a specific div?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` with `Modal` component, and I would like to append a `Modal` inside a specific div. Suppose I have this structure:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
  <div className="main">
    {children}
    <Footer />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want show the modal in the `main` div, so at the left of `container-fluid` I can see the navbar. So in the `Modal` component I have:

```
import { useIntl } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import { Row, Modal, Button, Form, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import BGTContext from "../../context/bgt/bgtContext"
import Localization from "../../helpers/localization"

export default function SectionModal({ show, onClose, section }) {
    const intl = useIntl()
  
    if (document.querySelector(".modal-backdrop") !== null)
      document.querySelector(".modal-backdrop").appendTo(".main")
      
  return (
    <Modal
      show={show}
      onHide={onClose}
      backdrop="static"
      keyboard={false}
      className="bgt-modal-fullscreen"
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <p>hello world</p>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555585/bootstrap-modal-window-inside-another-div) solution, but isn't working. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to your question is [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). You could easily do something like the following:

```
import { useIntl } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Row, Modal, Button, Form, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import BGTContext from "../../context/bgt/bgtContext"
import Localization from "../../helpers/localization"

export default function SectionModal({ show, onClose, section }) {
  const intl = useIntl()
      
  return ReactDOM.createPortal((
    <Modal
      show={show}
      onHide={onClose}
      backdrop="static"
      keyboard={false}
      className="bgt-modal-fullscreen"
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <p>hello world</p>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  ), document.querySelector(".main"));
}
```